# How to enable xt_bpf module in iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

I have run

```
cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
```

On my machine running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to check for loaded modules, it doesn't list the BPF module.

Comment: Hi , can some help to answer my query

Answer (score 2):

This is a kernel module, so you can load it the same way you would do for any other module: as root user, run `modprobe xt_bpf`.

```
# cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
icmp
# modprobe xt_bpf
# cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
bpf
icmp
```

(If needed, you can unload it later with `modprobe -r xt_bpf`.)